# How to map a List in Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, list, automapper

I have two classes:  `Role` and `RoleViewModel`.

**Role** class

```
public partial class Role
{
    public Role()
    {
        this.Users = new HashSet<User>();
    }

    public int RoleId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }
}
```

**RoleViewModel** class

```
public class RoleViewModel
{
    public RoleViewModel()
    {
        this.Users = new HashSet<UserViewModel>();
    }

    public int RoleId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<UserViewModel> Users { get; set; }
}
```

Now, I am trying to fetch a list of `Role` from database and `map` it to a list of `RoleViewModel`.

```
 public static List<RoleViewModel> GetRolesService()
 {
     List<Role> roles =MainRepository.GetUserRoles();
     var rolesVM = Mapper.Map<List<Role>, List<RoleViewModel>>(roles);
     return rolesVM;
 }
```

The problem is that `rolesVM` list always have `Count=0`, and I don't know why.

Thanks in advance!.

Comment: How? Where? are you initializing/configuring automapper? does `roles` has values?

Comment: Yes, i configuring automapper and `roles` has values

Comment: @stuartd, can you provide a solution for that ?

Comment: @stuartd if that were the case Automapper should raise an exception.... that `Role_F8BD4EA9D8D8C5563DC8033C7…` is not configured to be mapped.... or something like that

Comment: @jjchiw you're absolutely right, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution is to ignore nested dependencies.

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Role, RoleViewModel>().ForMember(c=>c.Users,option=>option.Ignore());
```